# best practice for form submission

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation, form-submit

I'm currently planning a robust form for a client that involves a lot of input. 
And I am looking for some best practices or opinions regarding submission.
I need to use asp.net and i work in jquery, c# and other .net frameworks.

So my question(s):
**What is the best way to submit a form?**

1. Should I validate using Javascript Client-side and server-side?
2. Whats the best way to validate server side? (asp.net C#)
   (edit: Whats the actual best practice for that, use the asp:requiredfieldvalidator etc or just write rules in the code behind? Throw errors? what do you think?)
3. Is it okay to use ajax to send the info to a public web method?
4. Are there security risks in using public web methods
5. <strike>What tactics do you use?</strike>
6. *(edit) How do you defend against people pressing esc or the x in the url bar when saving? (Im under the influence that stops your request in its tracks*

Comment: What presentation framework are you using?  Webforms, MVC, etc?

Comment: God, i actually don't know, the project comes with some legacy, so whatever that framework is in. I'll update when i find out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it makes a nicer user experience
2. Using ASP.NET validators http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx
3. Generally yes, but ASP usually needs a postback for anything to work.
4. If your form is encrypted, the target should be encrypted too
5. Be careful to not make complex ASP forms do stuff async. Plain ASP forms work well.

Comment: Fantastic answer! (edit: pressed the **** enter button when i wanted <br/>)... What is wrong with a complex form using async? less post backs = better in my opinion?

Comment: async updates has a tendency to make the page jump around, you lose focus on what you are doing and so on. It can be hard to do right with ASP.

Comment: Even for something as simple as: Press submit -> loading bar -> "complete ..."

Comment: I thinking about forms where input elements are removed&added depending on previous selections. Or list views that update when you click on filter input elements.

Comment: But isnt that necessary sometimes if the logic requires it?

Answer (score 0):

Should I validate using Javascript Client-side and server-side? **YES.**

Whats the best way to validate server side? **Make sure all the fields are valid, return a HTTP 400 error if not - Intercept that error w/ your AJAX handler and display an appropriate error. If you don't use AJAX, respond w/ a 200 that returns a complete error page**

Is it okay to use ajax to send the info to a public web method? **Sure, why not?**

Are there security risks in using public web methods? **YES.  w/o SSL, data is subject to being intercepted and/or modified by malicious attackers**

What tactics do you use? **Huh?**

Comment: "What tactics do you use? Huh?" Hahahaha, ill get rid of it. Now that i look at it, its not making sense. I sort of meant how do you do it?

Comment: This is a bad answer without any reasons why/why not, and why would you return a http 400 error to the user!

Comment: "why would you return a http 400 error to the user!" Beat me to it

Comment: @BrianMcFarland No that is not better. You have answered "yes" to one of his questions...that is not an good enough answer for SO. That is just one example of why your answer is a bad answer